# I'm new to visual basic and trying to understand how to set individual bits in a byte

Tags: vb.net, binary

Hi, I am new to Visual Basic, I have a project where I need to be able to manipulate individual bits in a value.

I need to be able to switch these bits between 1 and 0 and combine multiple occurrences of bits into one variable in my code.

Each bit will represent a single TRUE / FALSE value, so I'm not looking for how to do a single TRUE / FALSE value in one variable, but rather multiple TRUE / FALSE values in one variable.

Can someone please explain to me how I can achieve this please.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to have to clarify.  In VB.NET, True is **not** `01010100 01110010 01110101 01100101`.  Are you saying you have a program with an Integer (Int32) with the value of `1,416,787,301` (or `&H54727565` or `01010100 01110010 01110101 01100101` in binary) and want to convert that to either `True` or `1` when you display it on your user interface?

Comment: Actually what i want to do that suppose i have two binary values: one is 01010100 and the second one is 01100101 I want to make first value(01010100) = 1(bit) and second one(01100101) = 0(bit) now tell me how can i do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be exactly one bit?

Why don't you just use the actual built in VB data type of Boolean for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3(v=vs.80).aspx

It's sole reason for existence is so you can define variables that have 2 states, true or false.

```
Dim myVar As Boolean
myVar = True
myVar = Flase
if myVar = False Then
  myVar = True
End If
```

### UPDATE (1)

After reading through the various answers and comments from the OP I now understand what it is the OP is trying to achieve.

As others have said the smallest unit one can use in any of these languages is an 8 bit byte.  There is simply no order of data type with a smaller bit size than this.

However, with a bit of creative thinking and a smattering of binary operations, you can refer to the contents of that byte as individual bits.

First however you need to understand the binary number system:

ALL numbers in binary are to the power of two, from right to left.

Each column is the double of it's predecessor, so:

1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 4, 4 becomes 8 and so on

looking at this purely in a binary number your columns would be labelled thus:

**128  64  32  16  8  4  2  1** (Remember it's right to left)

this gives us the following:

```
The bit at position 1 = 1;
The bit at position 2 = 2;
The bit at position 3 = 4;
The bit at position 4 = 8;
```

and so on.

Using this method on the smallest data type you have (The byte) you can pack 8 bit's into one value.  That is you could use one variable to hold 8 separate values of 1 or 0

So while you cannot go any smaller than a byte, you can still reduce memory consumption by packing 8 values into 1 variable.

How do you read and write the values?

Remember the column positions? well you can use something called Bit Shifting and Bit masks.

Bit Shifting is the process of using the

```
<<
```

and

```
>>
```

operators

A shifting operation takes as a parameter the number of columns to shift.

EG:

```
Dim byte myByte
myByte = 1 << 4
```

In this case the variable 'myByte' would become equal to 16, but you would have actually set bit position 5 to a 1, if we illustrate this, it will make better sense:

```
mybyte = 0  = 00000000 = 0
mybyte = 1  = 00000001 = 1
mybyte = 2  = 00000010 = (1 << 1)
mybyte = 4  = 00000100 = (1 << 2)
mybyte = 8  = 00001000 = (1 << 3)
mybyte = 16 = 00010000 = (1 << 4)
```

the 0 through to 16 if you note is equal to the right to left column values I mentioned above.

given what Iv'e just explained then, if you wanted to set bits 5, 4 and 1 to be equal to 1 and the rest to be 0, you could simply use:

```
mybyte = 25(16 + 8 + 1) = 00011001 = (1 << 4) + (1 << 3) + 1
```

to get your bits back out, into a singleton you just bit shift the other way

```
retrieved bit = mybyte >> 4 = 00000001
```

Now there is unfortunately however one small flaw with the bit shifting method.

by shifting back and forth you are highly likely to LOOSE information from any bits you might already have set, in order to prevent this from happening, it's better to combine your bit shifting operations with bit masks and boolean operations such as 'AND' & 'OR'

To understand what these do you first need to understand simple logic principles as follows:

***AND***

Output is one if both the A and B inputs are 1

Illustrating this graphically

```
A  B | Output
-------------
0  0 | 0
0  1 | 0
1  0 | 0
1  1 | 1
```

As you can see if a bit position in our input number is a 1 and the same position in our input number B is 1, then we will keep that position in our output number, otherwise we will discard the bit and set it to a 0, take the following example:

```
00011001 = Bits 5,4 and 1 are set
00010000 = Our mask ONLY has bit 5 set
```

if we perform

```
00011001 AND 0010000
```

we will get a result of

```
00010000
```

which we can then shift down by 5

```
00010000 >> 5 = 00000001 = 1
```

so by using AND we now have a way of checking an individual bit in our byte for a value of 1:

```
if ((mybyte AND 16) >> 1) = 1 then
  'Bit one is set
else
  'Bit one is NOT set
end if
```

by using different masks, with the different values of 2 in the right to left columns as shown previously, we can easily extract different singular values from our byte and treat them as a simple bit value.

Setting a byte is just as easy, except you perform the operation the opposite way using an 'OR'

***OR***

Output is one if either the A or B inputs are 1

Illustrating this graphically

```
A  B | Output
-------------
0  0 | 0
0  1 | 1
1  0 | 1
1  1 | 1
```

eg:

```
00011001 OR 00000100 = 00011101
```

as you can see the bit at position 4 has been set.

To answer the fundamental question that started all this off however, you cannot use a data type in VB that has any resolution less than 1 byte, I suspect if you need absolute bit wise accuracy I'm guessing you must be writing either a compression algorithm or some kind of encryption system. :-)

Comment: Actually what i want to do that suppose i have two binary values:     one is 01010100 and the second one is 01100101                        I want to make first value(01010100) = 1(bit) and second one(01100101) = 0(bit) now tell me how can i do that

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by that comment can you describe in a bit more detail.  Boolean values are always 2 state generally -1 for False and 1 (or 0) for true (Can't remember the exact values it's been a while)

Comment: in simple words i want to compress these two values.                 i have only two value and i want to make them equal 1 and 0 to decrease the memory

Comment: Upvoted because this is an excellent and thorough explanation of a simple and logical way to manipulate binary without using an array of booleans or something ridiculous. Also a useful answer to the OP even if the question was closed.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :-)  It is unfortunate however that MANY programmers in this day and age are taught only to develop in a language and/or specific environment, and are not taught the art of software engineering.  As a result concepts like the above (Which I believe are essential to any good developer) are not taught, or even mentioned in many of these classes.  Its a sad reflection on the enterprise driven, do everything in a measured processed way shambles that our industry has become.

Answer (score 0):

01010100 01110010 01110101 01100101, is the string value of the word "TRUE"

What you want is to store the information in a boolean

```
Dim v As Boolean

v = True
v = False
```

or

```
If number = 84 Then ' 84 = 01010100 = T
    v = True
End If
```

**Other info**

Technicaly you can't store anything in a bit, the smallest value is a char which is 8 bit. You'll need to learn how to do bitwise operation. Or use the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class.

Comment: Actually what i want to do that suppose i have two binary values: one is 01010100 and the second one is 01100101 I want to make first value(01010100) = 1(bit) and second one(01100101) = 0(bit) i want to compress these values by one bit to decrease the memory size

Comment: I dont't want to store information in a boolean. As you said 84 = 01010100.i want to make 84 = 1. and for your understanding i only have two numbers 84 and 85 i want to make 84 = 1 and 85 = 0.

Comment: @user1990615 like I said, you can't store directly in a bit, you need to use a byte (or char) with BitWise operation or use the BitArray class.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET (nor any other .NET language that I know of) has a "bit" data type.  The smallest that you can use is a `Byte`.  (Not a `Char`, they are two-bytes in size).  So while you can read and convert a byte of value 84 into a byte with value 1 for true, and convert a byte of value 101 into a byte of value 0 for false, you are not saving any memory.

Now, if you have a small and fixed number of these flags, you CAN store several of them in one of the integer data types (in .NET the largest integer data type is 64 bits).  Or if you have a large number of these flags you can use the `BitArray` class (which uses the same technique but backs it with an array so storage capacity is greater).